# How to differentiate between clang and clang-cl?

Tags: cmake

I'm new to CMake and I've run into a little bit of a snag here, wondering if there is an "elegant" solution to this problem, or maybe there's just an easy solution.

As an example, for setting up compiler flags I'm doing the following:

```
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:"-some_gnu_flag">
        $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:"-some_clang_flag">
        $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:"/some_msvc_flag">
)
```

This works perfectly as expected, except for when I try a build using clang-cl as a compiler, ie:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -T "LLVM-vs2014"
```

The CXX ID is reported as Clang (*it is* clang after all) but I don't want to be using Clang flags, I actually want to be using MSVC flags since clang-cl is designed to be a drop in replacement for MSVCs cl - and hence only accepts MSVC style flags.

So what are some good solutions to this without creating some messy code? I know I could probably do a bunch of if() checks and set some variable, but I was trying to stick to "modern cmake" conventions, hence why I was using generator expressions to begin with.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857779.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is my current "solution". I found the CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID variable which holds the information I want  - although this still feels a bit dirty to me.

```
# Get compiler info
set(CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_GNU OFF)
set(CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_MSVC OFF)
set(CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_CLANGCL OFF)
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_GNU ON)
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
    if ("${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
        set(CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_CLANGCL ON)
    else ()
        set(CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_GNU ON)
    endif ()
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
    set(CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_MSVC ON)
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported compiler!")
endif ()

# Compiler flags
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        ## GCC/Clang Flags
        $<$<BOOL:${CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_GNU}>:"-someflag">
        ## MSVC flags
        $<$<BOOL:${CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_MSVC}>:"/someflag">
        ## CLANG-CL flags
        $<$<BOOL:${CXX_FLAGS_STYLE_CLANGCL}>:"-someflag">
)
```

Comment: Right, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` and `CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID` is the way to go.

Comment: There are only two styles: GNU and MSVC.
So for consistency, STYLE_CLANGCL should be removed in favor or STYLE_MSVC.
Note that recent versions of CMake suggest to use CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_FRONTEND_VARIANT instead of SIMULATE_ID for this purpose.