# cmake detects clang-cl as clang

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-cl

I built boringssl with cmake and msvc
Then I tried to build with clang-cl so I used -T"LLVM-vs2014" in vmake arguments

Clang-cl uses cl arguments however cmake used gcc style arguments without adding -Xclang

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to handle this case is checking for

```
(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL Clang AND "x${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID}" STREQUAL "xMSVC"))
```

Comment: Why the x is necessary before ${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID}?

Comment: He is using `"x${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID}"`. So if `${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID} == MSVC` you need to add `x`.

Comment: Is there any reason to put the x in both instead of doing `"${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC"`?

Comment: IIRC, the "x" is used near "MSVC" because MSVC itself is a CMake variable and the `if` command may dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was here :

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wshadow -Werror -Wno-error=shadow -Wno-error=unused-value -ggdb -std=gnu89")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wshadow -Werror -Wno-error=shadow -Wno-error=unused-value -ggdb -std=c++0x")
```

I changed Clang to Clng so clang-cl wasn't identified as clang.exe which take gcc style arguments

Comment: Can you clarify why you chose the string `Clng`? Is that an identifier for a specific version of clang, or is it meant as a random string that matches nothing?