# How to add compiler arguments for LLVM -clang-cl in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line-arguments, llvm-clang

I'm not actually sure how to properly add arguments for clang. I am pretty sure the problem is down to incorrect syntax. For example, when adding "-fno-vectorize" (as seen [here](https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#id3)) in Properties > Command Line > Additional Options, the compiler tells me

`1>clang-cl : warning : unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-fno-vectorize' [-Wunknown-argument]`

So, the compiler sees the arguments, just doesn't parse them correctly.

For MSVC flags look like "/Qpar" (for example this one turns on auto-parallelization) and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe clang-cl has a different argument syntax to clang.
For most arguments, you can refer to MSVC documentation.

Often, this means replacing "-" by "/" and "=" by ":", like so, but sometimes the arguments are different altogether.

```
-std=c++17
```

by

```
/std:c++17
```

To tell clang and clang-cl appart, you can use the following:

```
elseif(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
    if ("${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
```

As discussed here: [How to differentiate between clang and clang-cl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480535/how-to-differentiate-between-clang-and-clang-cl)